# PowerBI how to calculate response time with DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

For example:

1.7.2021 10.49.03 TAK001 received a message from VEH270 with MessageId "AS8PR01M"
3.7.2021 11.58.03 TAK001 replied for this message as AS8PR01M is found from References column and TAK001 is sender and DisplayTo is including VEH270.

I would need to calculate datedifference between these to dates. Could someone help to solve this, thanks?

```
Sender  DisplayTo         DateTimeSent          DateTimeReceived    MessageId   References
TAK001  TAM210            28.10.2021 11.31.48   28.10.2021 11.31.50 AM7PR01M    HE1PR0101
TAM210  TAK001            18.10.2021 11.24.18   18.10.2021 11.24.19 HE1PR0101   
TAK001  VEH270, TAA770    3.7.2021 11.58.03     3.7.2021 11.58.05   DU2PR01M    AS8PR01M
VEH270  TAK001            1.7.2021 10.48.59     1.7.2021 10.49.03   AS8PR01M
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, based on your example table: when there is a value in the `References` column, it means that this row is the reply to the referenced `MessageID`.

The most difficult thing based on your example is the handling or the time strings. `28.10.2021 11.31.48` cannot be handled as date/time out of the box.

So, here is the DAX for a calculated column to calculate the response time, in minutes:

```
ResponseTime =

VAR Date1_String = 
MINX(
    CALCULATETABLE(
        Table,
        [Reference] = EARLIER([MessageId])
    ),
    [DateTimeReceived]
)

VAR Date2_String = [DateTimeSent]

VAR Date1_Date = 
FORMAT(
    DATEVALUE(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            LEFT(
                Date1_String, 
                FIND(" ", Date1_String)
            ),
            ".",
            "/"
        )
    ),
    "dd/mm/yyyy"
) + 
TIMEVALUE(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        RIGHT(
            Date1_String, 
            FIND(" ", Date1_String)
        ),
        ".",
        ":"
    )
)

VAR Date2_Date = 
FORMAT(
    DATEVALUE(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            LEFT(
                Date2_String, 
                FIND(" ", Date2_String)
            ),
            ".",
            "/"
        )
    ),
    "dd/mm/yyyy"
) + 
TIMEVALUE(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        RIGHT(
            Date2_String, 
            FIND(" ", Date2_String)
        ),
        ".",
        ":"
    )
)

RETURN
IF(
    NOT ISBLANK([References]),
    DATEDIFF(
        Date1_Date,
        Date2_Date,
        MINUTE
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```

The code introduces a few variables :

- `Date1_String` retrieves the `DateTimeReceived` from the initial message searching for the message with the `MessageId` in the current `Reference` column.
- `Date2_String` is the `DateTimeSent` from the current line. i.e. the reply.
- `Date1_Date` and `Date2_Date` is a (slightly convoluted) way to parse the string into a workable date/time format.

After the `RETURN`, a simple IF statement than calculate the time difference in minutes between the two date if only the column `References` is not empty.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've now tried this code but however I get an error that "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected." Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: As far as I have now got I think this falls because LOOKUPVALUE will find multiple values. And I should find the first date. But how to do this is the big question.

Comment: @USSSR I was expecting `MessageId` to be unique. In that case, you replace the method in the VAR `Date1_String` with a MAXX/MINX. 

Please note, that in calculated column, LOOKUPVALUE is often prefered to other formulas such a RELATED, etc. Because it doesn't create a "hidden relationship" that results in error messages when trying to validate the calculted colummn. You should be good though.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by replacing it? Could you show what you mean? Thanks. @Jérémie L

Comment: I've edited the answer with a *new* `Date1_Date`. What it does it that it queries the *table* (don't know the actual name) to get lines where `References` corresponds to current `MessageId` and then the MINX returns the smallest `DateTimeReceived`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this at least someway sorted out:

Response time =

VAR Responseday = CALCULATE(

MIN(Sheet1[DateTimeReceived]),

FILTER(Sheet1,[References] = EARLIER([MessageId]))
)

VAR Receiveday = [DateTimeReceived]

RETURN

```
DATEDIFF(Receiveday,Responseday,DAY)
```

Comment: What part of your question does this answer, and what part remains to be solved?